# Not able to get actual values in decimal places in x axis of matplotlib plot in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I am not able to get the actual values in the decimal places in the x axis of matplotlib plot in python 2.7

```
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

start=2.0000
step=0.5555

z=pd.Series(index=range(0,32))

for i in  z.index:
    z[i]=start+step
    start= start+0.3333

x= range(0,32)
y=range(32,64)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot( z.astype(float),x, 'b-', label="Predicted")
ax.plot(z.astype(float),y, 'b-', color='r', label="Actual")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.4f'))

ax.legend(loc="best")
ax.set_xlabel('Week_number')
ax.set_ylabel('Weekly_Sales')
plt.title('Predictions')

fig
```

z values are

```
0      2.5555
1      2.8888
2      3.2221
3      3.5554
4      3.8887
5      4.2220
6      4.5553
7      4.8886
8      5.2219
9      5.5552
10     5.8885
11     6.2218
12     6.5551
13     6.8884
14     7.2217
15     7.5550
16     7.8883
17     8.2216
18     8.5549
19     8.8882
20     9.2215
21     9.5548
22     9.8881
23    10.2214
24    10.5547
25    10.8880
26    11.2213
27    11.5546
28    11.8879
29    12.2212
30    12.5545
31    12.8878
dtype: float64
```

Instead of actual z values,  x axis displays only zeroes in the 4 decimal places.

Am I missing something ?

[image: plot]

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest    Thanks, by using ax.set_xticks(z), I am able to get all the values in X axis in decimal places.  But they are all getting cluttered. How to space them out ie display only few of the labels ?  By using ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(majorLocator), it is getting spaced out, but I again get zeroes in the decimal places

Comment: solved........import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = [0,5,9,10,15]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
z=pd.Series(index=range(0,32))


for i in  z.index:
    z[i]=initial+step
    initial= initial+0.3333
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
start=z[0]
end=z[len(z)-1]
step=2
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, step))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.4f'))
plt.show()